# html form tag get method disable in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using asp.net with c# language. I have a master page and connected a page. On master page, I have already a server form tag, but on connected `.aspx` page, a simple form tag is there that contains asp button. So if I click on the asp button, it's not going to back-end c# code and this form tag generate a URL containing all input data. If I remove that form tag from `.aspx` page, then I can't click on asp button.

My front end code is:

```
<div class="registration_form">
     <!-- Form -->
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="first name:" id="txtfname" runat="server" type="text"  required>
                </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="last name:" id="txtlname" runat="server" type="text"  required>
                </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="email address:" id="txtemail" runat="server" type="text" required>
                </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

                <div>
               <label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddpgender" CssClass="dropdown" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </label>  
                &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

            <div>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="password" id="txtpass" runat="server" type="password" required>
                </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>                      
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="retype password" id="txtrpass" runat="server" type="password" required>
                </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>  

            <div class="sky-form">
                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ><i></i>i agree to shoppe.com &nbsp;<a class="terms" href="#"> terms of service</a> </label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        <div>
                <asp:Button ID="bttnsignup" runat="server" Text="Register" 
                    onclick="bttnsignup_Click" />
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Your masterpage probably already has it's own `<form>` tag, no need to define one in the nested page

Comment: It is not valid HTML to have a <form> tag inside another <form> tag. If you need to change where a button post you can add the PostBackUrl attribute to an asp:Button and it will override the forms original post url. If you need to build a special URL with all the inputs as a query i think you are going to have to write some javascript for that. Is this what you need? Do you know how to do this or do you want an example?

Comment: Noh sir actually listen i have a master page and connected .aspx page i have placed server form tag already on master page okey.... 
but as actually i am using a template design so in page already a form tag is there and all input tags in that form tag so i placed my asp button in that and wrote the coding onclik event of button. but its not working when i click the button its just loading and give an url thats it. i want that when i click on asp button it should run the backend code